# Prevent anchor behaviour

Tags: javascript

When I want to prevent default behaviour of anchor tag I`m using

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);">link</a>
```

Which is the most effective solution ?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

An example of a gracefully degrading solution:

```
<a href="no-script.html" id="myLink">link</a>

<script>
document.getElementById("myLink").onclick = function() {
    // do things, and then
    return false;
};
</script>
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/karim79/PkgWL/1/

Comment: This will also take the user to the no-script page if an error occurs in *do things* or if the user clicks the link before the listener is assigned. The latter is not likely to happen if you actually intend for them to be immediately after one another in the DOM, as in your example, but that would inhibit page rendering speed, as well as break validation (unless this is changed in HTML5 specs? I wouldn't mind if it was!) Usually, these things are assigned at DOMReady at the very soonest, which can in some cases leave a considerable window for the user to click the link.

Answer (score 38):

This is a nice approach, if you're using jquery you can also do:

```
<a id="link" href="javascript:void(0)">link</a>

<script type="text/javascript">
   $("#link").click(function(ev) {
       ev.preventDefault();
   });
</script>
```

preventDefault can be useful also to prevent submitting form

Answer (score 21):

You can also have this:

```
<a href="#" onclick="return false;">link</a>
```

Answer (score 10):

If you never want for the browser to follow the link anywhere, I'd say what you've got is the simplest, safest solution.

Sure, there are heaps of other solutions you could apply with javascript, but most other ways may fail when

- The DOM is not completely loaded, if the event is assigned at DOMReady or later, which is common.
- A click event listener handles the link (which is common where you want links not to be followed by the browser). If an error occurs in the javascript that handles the click, the `return false;` or `preventDefault` that might be at the end of the statement, will not be executed, and the browser will follow the link, if only to `#`.

Answer (score 7):

I know it's an old thread but here is what I use often

#### Instead of this:

`<a href="javascript:void(0);">link</a>`

#### This also can work:

`<a href="javascript:;">link</a>`

Answer (score 3):

Here is very easy way to stop this.

```
( function( $ ) {
   $( 'a[href="#"]' ).click( function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
   } );
} )( jQuery );
```

Comment: That's using jQuery. They didn't say they're using it, and you didn't suggest using that library.