# Prevent an anchor from following href

Tags: javascript, html

I have an anchor defined as follows -

```
<a onClick="javascript:isLinked('');" class="..." href="..."><img border="0" alt="" height="8" width="8" src="..."/> <u>Add another</u></a>
```

The javascript function -

```
function isLinked(sId) {
        if(!sId)
        {
            alert(".....");
            return false;
        }
        else
            document.body.style.cursor='wait';                  
    }
```

Although I do see the alert being triggered on the click of the anchor,the links still follows the target url.
How can i prevent the link from following?

The browser is IE8(if that is relevant)

Comment: use `e.preventDefault();` and `return false;` but for that you should have e in event source in your function

Comment: I think this question is similar to [prevent-anchor-behaviour](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4387580/prevent-anchor-behaviour)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to return the value returned by the method from onclick handler

```
onClick="return isLinked('');"
```

Answer (score 0):

The **javascript** way to disable a link is to add `return false;`. In your case, the boolean is determined by your function *isLinked*. So the answer is :

```
<a onClick="return isLinked('');" class="..." href="..."><img ...
```

In case that might be of use to you, there's also a **css** way of disabling links, as documented [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2091168/disable-a-link-using-css).