# Any way to disable link functionality of #my_div without extracting it from "a"?

Tags: html, hyperlink

Yes, this may seem a bit weird but I would like to disable the link functionality of #my_div without extracting it from a. Is there a way?

```
<a href="#" > 
<div id="my_div"></div> 
</a>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Prevent anchor behaviour](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4387580/prevent-anchor-behaviour)

Answer (score 0):

You could change the link to an empty javascript call:

```
<a href="javascript:">
   <div id="my_div"></div> 
</a>
```