# prevent default link action with addeventlistener

Tags: javascript

```
<a id="link" href="example.com">test</a>

var a = document.getElementById(link);
a.addEventListener('click',function(e){
//code
}, false);
```

How can I prevent the link action to go to example.com?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Prevent anchor behaviour](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4387580/prevent-anchor-behaviour)

Comment: return false doesn't work on eventlistener

Comment: @machiine there are other options too suggested in that thread.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Event handlers that are registered with `.addEventListener()` (the modern, standard way to register events), are automatically passed a reference to the `event` object that represents the event that triggered the handler in the first place. This `event` object has many properties, but the following two are what you are looking for:

- [`event.preventDefault()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault)
- [`event.stopPropagation()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation)

```js
document.getElementById("link").addEventListener('click',function(e){
   e.preventDefault(); // Cancel the native event
   e.stopPropagation();// Don't bubble/capture the event any further
});
```

```html
<a id="link" href="example.com">test</a>
```

Comment: Should be `"link"`