# Stopping submitting when alert is shown

Tags: javascript, html

I have form that has text `input` and `submit`. I'm trying to show an alert with Javascript if input is empty.

**This is my code:**

```js
String.prototype.trim = function() {
  return this.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, "");
}

function emptyArea() {
  if (document.getElementById("type-text").value.trim() == '') {
    alert("Please fill all fields");
  } else("OK");
}
```

```html
<form>
  <input id="type-text" type="text" placeholder="Type some text">
  <input type="submit" placeholder="Submit" onclick="emptyArea()">
</form>
```

When I click `submit` and it is empty, form still submits and doesn't show the alert. How would I prevent it from submitting and instead show an alert?

Comment: Just call `return false` at the end inside `emptyArea()` function.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Can you please provide us with your HTML code as well? Is the `submit` button presumably inside a `<form>`? Also, above is `JavaScript` code, not `Java`, just for clarification :)

Comment: You might want to make sure trim() is not defined before overriding it. Example on how on MDN https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/trim#Polyfill

Comment: You seem to be confusing Java and JavaScript. They are completely different programming languages.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. Use the live demo feature of the question editor.

Comment: Well you should cancel the form submission if you are going to use a submit button. Posting a the html and javascript you are using would make it easier to debug.

Comment: if you want to make sure that an input is entered just add required to the input and forget about your js.

Comment: @Quentin I am sorry for typing "Java" ( I meant Javascript ). B1CL0PS' answer helped me. I edited my question with full code.

Comment: @epascarello as your link shows,  [.trim()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/trim) is supported since IE9

Comment: Also NEVER call anything "submit" in a form. If you ever want to use script to submit the form, you will not be able to

Comment: @mplungjan your point with IE9 is? I was pointing out the flaw with the OPs code.

Comment: I was just agreeing with you, noting that it is not even needed to add trim yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I run your code, I actually do get alerts when I click "submit". Are you sure you are attaching the event handler correctly? I'm guessing maybe what's actually happening is that the alert is showing but then it submits anyway no matter if the form value is valid.

If you want to prevent the form from submitting, call [`e.preventDefault()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40722385/prevent-default-link-action-with-addeventlistener) where `e` is the event object which will be passed as the first argument to your handler function.

Here is an example codepen:
https://codepen.io/quinnfreedman/pen/PoqmGYb

```js
function emptyArea(e) {
  if (document.getElementById("text").value.trim() == '') { // .trim is supported by browsers since IE9
    alert("Please fill all fields");
    // the conditions were not met, so call preventDefault to 
    // stop the browsers default behavior of submitting the form
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
  } else {
    // If we don't preventDefault, the form will submit after this alert
    alert("OK")
  }
}

document.getElementById("Submit").addEventListener("click", emptyArea)
```

```html
<form action="#">
  <input type="text" id="text" />
  <input type="submit" id="Submit" />
  <!-- NEVER call anything "submit" in a form -->
</form>
```