Warning: Undefined array key "email" in login_capture.php on line 4
how are you doing?
A HTML form data is being captured (email and password) and then sent in an Ajax call to a PHP file to compare it from there with what's in the database = to login or not.
Editor
The PHP file doesn't want to recognise the data that's been captured in the form.
Browser

I am not concerned with hashing passwords, this is all for database testing purposes;
HTML elements and attributes are correct;
The Ajax call is set up correctly;
POST and not GET is used throughtout;
The server is not running any errors and is responding 200 OK;
In developer tools the payload is showing the typed email and password as being sent over to the PHP file;
The if (isset($_POST['email'], $_POST['password'])) hasn't helped;

Any ideas would be mighty helpful!

what outcome you expect from that header Location exactly?

Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.

Your second image clearly shows a GET request.

The if (isset($_POST['email'], $_POST['password'])) hasn't helped...well you haven't used those in the code you've shown, so obviously they won't help. If you did use them correctly in the right place, it would prevent the warnings

POST and not GET is used throughtout...the second screenshot shows the form values have been submitted as part of the URL, rather than the request body. That typically happens when you use a GET rather than a POST. So double-check your code. Show us your html form if you're still unsure.

Just a note as well to point out that your code doesn't actually check that the password matches anything stored on the server

What's the reason for the params: before the array in your execute() call? I've never used that in my PDO code, just the array containing the parameters.

@droopsnoot named parameters were introduced in PHP 8. https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.named-arguments . It's not specific to PDO. In this case it's not particularly useful because the execute() function only takes one argument anyway (and therefore there's no ambiguity about which argument is which) but there's nothing inherently wrong with it.

@ADyson thanks for the note, that at least explains why I couldn't find a reference to it in the PDO documentation. More reading for me, by the look of it. And in this case, of course, the error occurs before it gets to that point and is more likely your comment above about passing params via $_GET.

@shingo Thank you for your message!
I am curious why you point out a GET method - the Ajax call below sets up the POST method:

@shingo
const alertTriggerLogin = document.getElementById('loginBtn');
alertTriggerLogin.addEventListener('click', () => {
if (validateFormLog()) { 
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'login_capture.php',
        data: $('#myFormLogin').serialize(),
        success: function (response) {
            console.log("Success!"); 
        },
        error: function (xhr, status, error) {
            console.error('Error:', error);
        }
    });
}

});

So there's ajax involved? You didn't think that was worth mentioning before?? But everything about your screenshot strong suggests that the ajax call didn't fire, probably because you didn't suppress your form's default submit action when you handled the click event. Those errors would have shown in the console, not in the page, if they were the result of the ajax request, because that's where your ajax code logs its response to. Also the ajax call wouldn't cause the url of the page to change to include the form parameters in the querystring because ajax requests are separate in the background

So everything points to the request not being done via ajax, but by a regular form submission, and using GET

@ADyson Thank you for your message!
isset() tells us that the value exists or doesn't, if I understand correctly? It doesn't tell us why the value is NULL and PHP isn't picking it up from the Ajax call.

@ADyson
prepare('SELECT * FROM user_data WHERE email = ?');
    $stmt->execute([$email]);
    $user = $stmt->fetch();
    if ($user && $password) {
        $_SESSION['user_id'] = $user['id'];
        header('Location: http://localhost:8001/{...}/login_capture.php');
    } else {
        echo 'Invalid email or password.';
    }
}
Code in comments is really hard to read. [Edit] your question if you have updates, and use a code block for any code you include. See also [ask]. Comments are just for brief suggestions or clarification- it's not a chat forum. Thanks

@ADyson Page 1:
Existing user? Please login:





<input autocomplete="off" type="password" class="form-control" id="yourPasswordLogin"
@ADyson Page 2:
                        name="password" required placeholder="Password">
                </div>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-secondary" id="loginBtn">Login<span
                        class="spinner-border spinner-border-sm" role="status" aria-hidden="true" id="spinnerLogin"
                        style="display: none;"></span></button>
                <div id="liveAlertPlaceholder"></div>
            </form>


As I just pointed out a few minutes ago this is unreadable. [Edit] your question please and use the code formatting tools in the editor. Thanks

@ADyson OK, I understand, apologies.

But anyway I think I already told you what the problem is.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/40722425/5947043 shows the basic principle to prevent the default action of submitting the form normally (the usage applies just as much to buttons as to links)

@ADyson Thanks very much indeed for the time you've taken to offer feedback, I really appreciate it!
