# JQ or JS: Prevent "a" tag to change url #hash

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, hash

I'm trying to prevent any clicks on the "a" tags that have a class name "disable", I have tried a lot of codes but none have prevented the "a"...

```html
          <a href="#view-home" class="tab-link tab-link-active">
            <i class="icon f7-icons ios-only">today</i>
            <i class="icon f7-icons ios-only icon-ios-fill">today</i>
            <i class="icon material-icons md-only">today</i>
            <span class="tabbar-label">Home</span>
          </a>
          <a href="#view-games" class="tab-link disable">
            <i class="icon f7-icons">rocket_fill</i>
            <i class="icon f7-icons ios-only icon-ios-fill">rocket_fill</i>
            <span class="tabbar-label">Games</span>
          </a>
          <a href="#view-todo" class="tab-link disable">
            <i class="icon f7-icons">layers_alt_fill</i>
            <i class="icon f7-icons ios-only icon-ios-fill">layers_alt_fill</i>
            <span class="tabbar-label">Todo</span>
          </a>
          <a onclick="loadFirebase()" href="#view-download" class="tab-link disable">
            <i class="icon f7-icons">download_fill</i>
            <i class="icon f7-icons ios-only icon-ios-fill">download_fill</i>
            <span class="tabbar-label">Download</span>
          </a>
          <a onclick="loadFirebase()" href="#view-search" class="tab-link disable">
            <i class="icon f7-icons ios-only">search</i>
            <i class="icon f7-icons ios-only icon-ios-fill">search</i>
            <i class="icon material-icons md-only">search</i>
            <span class="tabbar-label">Search</span>
          </a>
```

This code give me an alert but it still changes the #hash to change page.

```
$('a#preventPage').on('click', function(event) {
  alert("Prevent");
  event.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: Try this `<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="fn()">fn is called</a>`

Comment: @SouravDutta I don't get it, sorry for being unclear but i want to prevent it using JQ or JS because I only want to prevent it when you aren't signed in. Thanks for helping.

Comment: Check this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4387580/prevent-anchor-behaviour)

Comment: Try this it's jQuery `$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#exampleLink').click(function() {
        alert('You clicked the link.');
        return false;
    });
});`

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't prevent the #hash going throw :(

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick:

```js
Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('a.disable')).forEach(c => {
  c.href = '';
  c.onclick = e => e.preventDefault();
});
```

```html
<a href="#view-home" class="tab-link tab-link-active">
  <i class="icon f7-icons ios-only">today</i>
  <i class="icon f7-icons ios-only icon-ios-fill">today</i>
  <i class="icon material-icons md-only">today</i>
  <span class="tabbar-label">Home</span>
</a>
<a href="#view-games" id="preventPage" class="tab-link disable">
  <i class="icon f7-icons">rocket_fill</i>
  <i class="icon f7-icons ios-only icon-ios-fill">rocket_fill</i>
  <span class="tabbar-label">Games</span>
</a>
<a href="#view-todo" class="tab-link disable">
  <i class="icon f7-icons">layers_alt_fill</i>
  <i class="icon f7-icons ios-only icon-ios-fill">layers_alt_fill</i>
  <span class="tabbar-label">Todo</span>
</a>
<a onclick="loadFirebase()" href="#view-download" class="tab-link disable">
  <i class="icon f7-icons">download_fill</i>
  <i class="icon f7-icons ios-only icon-ios-fill">download_fill</i>
  <span class="tabbar-label">Download</span>
</a>
<a onclick="loadFirebase()" href="#view-search" class="tab-link disable">
  <i class="icon f7-icons ios-only">search</i>
  <i class="icon f7-icons ios-only icon-ios-fill">search</i>
  <i class="icon material-icons md-only">search</i>
  <span class="tabbar-label">Search</span>
</a>
```

Comment: Nothing happens, i'm still getting to the #hash page ):

Comment: This did prevent the click, but i want to be able to click the button, get an alert saying it's disabled and then prevent the #hash to go throw.

Comment: How are you exactly making sure this doesn't work and the hash is being added? @Miroslav code seems fine. Although I would use destructing of `NodeList` instead of `Array.from` like so `[...document.querySelectorAll('a.tab-link.disable')].forEach(...)`.

Comment: @andris.vilde Because his code is preventing the click of the button. I want to be able to click the button but preventing the #hash to be added.

Answer (score 0):

Hey your code should be :

```
$('a.disable').each(function(){
          $(this).click( function(event) {
             alert("Prevent");
             event.preventDefault();
          });
     });
```

Comment: This code diden't even give me a alert for some reson

Comment: @Gnusson try another time i change the class disabled to disable now

Comment: the #hash is still changing the page

Comment: This does't work, i get the alert but it do not prevent the #hash

Comment: Maybe you have another script how do this.

Comment: I have no clue what to do ):

Answer (score 0):

Add an custom event listener and prevent the default listener which is added automatically on `a` tags.

```js
[...document.querySelectorAll('a.disable')].forEach(element => {
  element.addEventListener('click', event => {
    event.preventDefault();
    alert('prevented disabled button');
  });
});
```

```css
a {
  font-family: Tahoma;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 3px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
  padding: 5px;
}

a.disable {
  color: darkgrey;
}

a:hover {
  background-color: lightgray;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <a href="#home">Home</a>
  <a href="#work">Work</a>
  <a href="#nowhere" class="disable">Nowhere</a>
</div>
```

Comment: This dosen't prevent the hash on framework 7 unfortunately