# anchor with full link smoothscrolling

Tags: javascript, smooth-scrolling, anchor-scroll

hello I have a site with few pages and on one of them I wanted to use anchors and I need all of them in the top menu at all times.
So I added to anchors full link https://premiumfoams.com/branze.html#section7

I wanted to use smooth scrolling since it doesn't reload when there is the same page

going into page with smoothscrolig **works** (i got a script for that)

going from one section to another on one page just jumps. cant get the script to recognize the anchor within probably
Please help!

Comment: show your code - here, so no dead links will make this thread unhelpful later. How are your anchors defined and how do you link to them - have you taken care to avoid "defaultBehaviour" like described in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4387580/prevent-anchor-behaviour or https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a

Comment: Hey Jerzy,
Welcome to StackOverflow! As Flowtron already mentions: please share your code. We can't help if we are not able to reproduce your problem. Please read '[How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)'.