# No button on confirm dialog not stopping the code execution

Tags: javascript, html

I want the code execution to stop when `No` button is clicked but it seems to be moving with the href link even after clicking on `No` button. Am I doing something wrong here?

```js
function checkType(){

let realFunctionReturn = false;

if (confirm('Ok or NO?')) {

// Save it!

console.log('Ok button clicked!');

realFunctionReturn = true;

} else {

// Do nothing!

console.log('No button cicked');

realFunctionReturn = false;

}

return realFunctionReturn;

}
```

```html
<tr>

<td><a href="somepage.htm" class="urlLink" title="Activate" onclick="checkType()" > Activate </a></td>

</tr>
```

Comment: everything your function does is just return true or false. Where do you tell your code what to do with that return value?

Comment: Although there is a lot that can be changed, this should work as you aren't using the return anywhere `onclick="return checkType()"`

Comment: @ChrisG Instead of `realFunctionReturn ` I have tried using `return true` for `Ok` button and `return false` for `No` button. that didn't work either.

Comment: @imvain2 is right, all you need to do is add "return" to your onclick handler.   Your function is returning the right value, but you're not currently doing anything with the returned value. The onclick itself needs to explicitly return false to prevent the navigation from occurring.

Comment: @DanielBeck Ok, so something like this `onclick="checkType() return;"` ?

Comment: No, just like @imvain2 said above:  `onclick="return checkType()"` (because you want the  handler to return the output of `checkType()`)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4387580/prevent-anchor-behaviour

Comment: Thanks everyone `onclick="return checkType()"` did the trick!